# How I can get the card id with onClick in react?

Tags: reactjs

here is a piece of code of the favorite.jsx class used on the card, when I press the favorite it will change the color of heart icon. However, I want it to console.log the id of that specific card too. can you help me please?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import resturants from '../resturants';

const gray = 'gray';
const red = 'red';

export default class Favorite extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
        color: gray 
    };

    this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this);
  }

  changeColor(){
    
    const newColor = this.state.color == gray ? red : gray;
    this.setState({ color: newColor })
    console.log();
    // make post request axios 
  }
  render(){
    return(
       <i className="favorite fa fa-heart" onClick={this.changeColor} style={{color: this.state.color}}></i>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the resturant.js class, which has all data needed to create the card including the id

```
const resturants = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Macdolands",
      stars: 3.3,
      favorite: "Fulled heart",
      types: "Fastfood",
      imgURL:
        "https://rinnoo.net/f/CMS/Listings/15_Mcdonalds-Restaurant-Logo_-_Qu80_RT1600x1024-_OS300x300-_RD300x300-.jpg",
      status: "Open!",
      descreption: "Macdolands is a fast food resturant that is famous with Big mac! Macdolands is a fast food resturant that is famous with Big mac! Macdolands is a fast food resturant that is famous with Big mac!",
      filters: "Music"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "herfy",
      stars: 4.2,
      userRate:0,
      favorite: "Fulled heart",
      types: "Fastfood",
      imgURL:
        "https://rinnoo.net/f/CMS/Listings/15_Mcdonalds-Restaurant-Logo_-_Qu80_RT1600x1024-_OS300x300-_RD300x300-.jpg",
      status: "Open!",
      descreption: "Macdolands is a fast food resturant that is famous with Big mac! Macdolands is a fast food resturant that is famous with Big mac! Macdolands is a fast food resturant that is famous with Big mac!",
      filters: "Music"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "MacdolandsMacdolandsMacdolands",
      stars: 2.4,
      favorite: "Fulled heart",
      types: "Fastfood",
      imgURL:
        "https://rinnoo.net/f/CMS/Listings/15_Mcdonalds-Restaurant-Logo_-_Qu80_RT1600x1024-_OS300x300-_RD300x300-.jpg",
      status: "Closed!",
      descreption: "Macdolands is a fast food resturant that is famous with Big mac! Macdolands is a fast food resturant that is famous with Big mac! Macdolands is a fast food resturant that is famous with Big mac!",
      filters: "Music"
    }
  ];
  
  export default resturants;
```

The card code

```
import React from "react";
import Avatar from "./Avatar";
import Detail from "./Detail";
import ReadStars from "./Star-rating";
import Favorite from "./Favorite";


function Card(props) {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <Avatar img={props.img} />
      <div className="flexname">
        <h2 className="name">{props.name}</h2>
        {/* <Star className="rating">{props.stars}</Star> */}
        <ReadStars className="rating" value={props.stars}></ReadStars>
      </div>
      <div className="flexfav">
        <h3 className="status">{props.status}</h3>
        <Favorite className="favorite">{props.favorite}</Favorite>
      </div>
      <h4 className="types">{props.types}</h4>
      <h4 className="filters">{props.filters}</h4>
      <Detail detailInfo={props.descreption} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: please add code for card

Comment: you need to pass the card data in the props. Then you will be able to log the card data

Comment: yep, id should be in initial props and set into state or at least captured in `this.changeColor(this.props.id)`

Comment: I updated my answer to include your Card code specifically, though this didn't fundamentally change my proposed solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Punith mentioned in the comments, you should pass the card ID to your Favorite component.

I am assuming that the `Favorite` component is used in the `Card` component. I'm also assuming that each `Card` component has a unique ID.

For your card code:

```
function Card(props) {
  return (
     <div>
      {// lots of Card markup...}
      <Favorite className="favorite">{props.favorite}</Favorite>
     </div>
  )
}
```

If that's the case, then in the `Card` you need to add `someId` as a prop to `Favorite`

```
<Favorite cardId={props.theCardId} className="favorite">{props.favorite}</Favorite>
```

Then in the `Favorite` component, you can use the prop you are passing - note the "UPDATED LINE" here:

```js
export default class Favorite extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
        color: gray 
    };

    this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this);
  }

  changeColor(){
    
    const newColor = this.state.color == gray ? red : gray;
    this.setState({ color: newColor })
    console.log(this.props.cardId);  // <----- UPDATED LINE ~~~~~~
    // make post request axios 
  }
  render(){
    return(
       <i className="favorite fa fa-heart" onClick={this.changeColor} style={{color: this.state.color}}></i>
    )
  }
}
```